# Core Motion Gyroscope 360 degree values

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, gyroscope, core-motion

I am testing Core Motion and using the gyroscope.  Right now I am getting values that I am not understanding.  My assumption was that with each x, y and z I would get a value between 0-360 which would be a full rotation, but this isn't the case.

```
[self.motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
     NSString *x = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",gyroData.rotationRate.x];
     NSLog(@"X: %@", x);

     NSString *y = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",gyroData.rotationRate.y];
     NSLog(@"Y: %@", y);

     NSString *z = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",gyroData.rotationRate.z];
     NSLog(@"Z: %@", z);

    frequency = gyroData.rotationRate.y*500;

    float rate = gyroData.rotationRate.z;
    if (fabs(rate) > .2) {
        float direction = rate > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        rotation += (direction * M_PI/90.0)*1000;
        NSLog(@"Rotation: %f", rotation);
    }

 }];
```

It is possible to get more human readable rotation values?  Is my assumption that I should be getting values between 0-360 wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are in radians, not degrees, so they should be between 0 and 2Pi. Also, they are a rate, not an angle. They are radians per second.

Comment: Ok. So does the device know the number of times I have rotated it?

Comment: I don't think so. It just gives you the angular rate that it's turning at (say Pi / 3 radians per second). Your application would need to track that over time to determine how many times it's been rotated.

Comment: Ok, so how do I know what angle the phone is at?  Isn't that what the gyroscope can be used for?  Such as apps that have a level or games the roll a ball?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053793/iphone-core-motion-relative-rotation).