# Track iphone camera movements

Tags: iphone, opencv

I want manage my iphone camera movements to take panoramic view.want to know if user rotates camera correct direction to get similar images.

Is possible OpenCV iphone framework or any other library available for the same?

Help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want the iphone specific library [Core Motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html) though.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053793/iphone-core-motion-relative-rotation) SO question should be useful, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html) is some explanation from the library itself